# I don't know how to trigger an AWS Lambda function made in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

In my case, I have written this class:

```
public class ListAndFindModified : AWSEventHandler
{
    /*Here I put all the variables*/

    public ListAndFindModified() : this(Startup.Container.BuildServiceProvider())
    { }

    public ListAndFindModified(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        /*Here I intialized all the variables (services) I need in my procedure*/
    }

    [LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]
    public void FunctionHandler(LambdaCalloutEvent evnt, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Received event: {0}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(evnt));
        if (evnt.RequestType != LambdaCalloutRequestType.Create)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Avoiding execution for request type {0}", evnt.RequestType);
            _cfnResponseService.SendResponse(evnt, context, CfnResponseStatus.Success, evnt, null, false);
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            /*Here I put all my business logical
              It's about to list a directory, and find which files had been updated in last 4 
              hours.. the that files will be witten in another location.
              So, the trigger is each 4 hours*/

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError("{0} {1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace);
            _cfnResponseService.SendResponse(evnt, context, CfnResponseStatus.Failed, e, null, true);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is "Where should I Put the trigger, or where i can define the "moments" that my LAMBDA FUNCTION will be executed.

Thanks anyway...

Comment: Inside your aws cli. That is not part of the code.

Comment: What do you want to trigger your Lambda function to be invoked? Typically you would configure an event trigger in another service such as S3, SNS, SQS, EventBridge etc.